# Structuring a database table with many columns for spreadsheet import; possibility to scale

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, database-design

A client wants to be able to import a fairly hefty spreadsheet of data (to my eyes, at least) on a monthly basis. At the moment it consists of around 200 rows, and 41 columns.

The first two columns are identifiers (an ID and a human-readable name for a location); the next 39 columns are all numerical values. These numbers are effectively 'ratings' that are split into 39 categories - however the client has just hinted that they may want to expand these categories in the future.

My initial thoughts were to create a database structure that imitates the spreadsheet (so, 41 columns, essentially) - however with the potential for the client to want to add to it later, I don't know if that's the best method to approach this with.

I'm not a classically-trained coder; I've just picked things up as I've needed to, so the more straightforward the solution, the better. I have considered *perhaps* serializing an associative array on a per-location basis:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
 ID     Name        Data                            Date
----------------------------------------------------------
 1      Newport     {niceness:1, staff:6.5, etc.}   Mar 13
 2      Stobart     {niceness:7, staff:3.1, etc.}   Mar 13
----------------------------------------------------------
```

...but I don't know if that's the best approach, or if it will necessarily work the way I envisage. The idea being that, if **March '13** only has 39 categories, but **July '13** has 42 categories, then the database structure won't have to be affected; just a different associative array stored.

This kind of thing would also potentially(?) remove the possibility for column mismatch errors when importing the table - for example, if they suddenly decide to drop a category without warning, then try importing an spreadsheet that's a column short.

**Things of note:**

I am developing this is a Wordpress plugin, so the database table structure is written in there and would be fairly straightforward to update, thanks to WP's [dbDelta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Creating_or_Updating_the_Table) function.

I'm also looking to use Matt Kruse's [PHP ExcelReader](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/), which in my initial tests appears to be excellent.

Comment: if the client doesn't need statistics of that table then a column with serialized data should be fine. Another approach is [Entity–attribute–value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would split tables into *names, categories* and a link-table called *names_categories* (or similar)

**table Names**

```
----------------------------------------------------------
 ID     Name        Date                    
----------------------------------------------------------
 1      Newport     Mar 13
 2      Stobart     Mar 13
```

**table Categories**

```
----------------------------------------------------------
 ID     Category                                    
----------------------------------------------------------
 1      niceness
 2      staff
```

**table names_categories** (link-table)

```
----------------------------------------------------------
 id_name    id_category value                           
----------------------------------------------------------
 1          1           1
 1          2           6.5
 2          1           7
 2          2           3.1
```

This would give you more flexibility. Even if your solution works, it's not that flexible and could be hard to do maintenance of the database in future.

Comment: Thanks @bestprogrammerintheworld - I like this and had considered doing something similar (based on WP's own `meta` tables); however I'm not 100% certain how to reliably shift the imported spreadsheet data into the link table whilst retaining the associations without still having to do a column count. The issue is that (predictably) _a number_ of employees maintain their spreadsheet, so things like changing case & typos in column headers can have a bearing. I'd need to **know** that column 4 is 'niceness' to grant it the right ID for association. It's late - am I making sense?

Comment: @indextwo - why not add a field into categories-table where you specify which column the category belongs to?

Comment: Thanks for this - it's a good idea. However, the client has since specified a bunch of extra requirements that have since rendered this question moot, so we need to look at a different approach for collating the data. I've accepted your answer as it's probably the way I would have done this if it had gone ahead.

Comment: As usual specifications change :-) Thanks :-)